# Output last and popular youtube videos on site ? any api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to output last videos and popular videos of my youtube channel.
Is there any standart widget, api method for this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701648/4241842), you can use the YouTube Data V3 API to get the uploads playlist ID, which you can then use to get the latest videos in that playlist. You can change the value of `maxResults` to return however many videos you want (from 0 to 50).

Use the [search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method to get your most viewed videos by specifying the `channel ID` and setting `order=viewcount` (not quite sure what you want when you say popular videos, you could also set `order=rating` to get the highest rated videos). [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcrG0_XTO9o) might also help you out.

Comment: You could also try using the GET request or API explorer to get your most viewed videos [(documentation)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests#my-most-viewed-videos).